# Heroku Python Flask app get Status 400 on Heroku when running fine locally

Tags: python, flask, heroku

Fairly new to Flask and deployment on Heroku. I have a Flask App that runs fine locally. However, when uploading to heroku I get a status=400

**Test.py**

```
import requests
import json

BASE = "https://mybot.herokuapp.com/"


InitialisationDic2=[
    {
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    }, 
    {
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    { 
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    {
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    { 
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    {
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    { 
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    {
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },
    { 
        'Concept': "Text1", 
        'Caption': "Text2"
    },

    ]

InitialisationDic = json.dumps(InitialisationDic2)

postRequest = "postRequestString"
postLanguage = "post Language string"
payload = {'Initialisation' : InitialisationDic , 'postRequest':postRequest , 'postLanguage': postLanguage}

response = requests.get(BASE+"caption", params=payload)

print(response.json())
```

**mybot.py**

```
from io import DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE
from logging import debug
from flask.wrappers import Response
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv #Load our .env file
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse, abort
from os import replace
from Caption import getCaption
from ExtractInput import extractInputCSV
from WriteOutput import OutputCSV
from progress.bar import Bar
import Translation
import json

env_path= Path('.') / '.env' 
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path) 

app= Flask(__name__) 
api = Api(app) 

payload = reqparse.RequestParser()
payload.add_argument('Initialisation', action='append')
payload.add_argument('postRequest', type=str, help="Need Caption request", required=True)
payload.add_argument('postLanguage', type=str, help="Need Output Language", required=True)


class CaptionHelper(Resource): 
    def get(self):
        print("\n\n Received Info:")
        args = payload.parse_args()
        brandInfo2=args['Initialisation']
        brandInfo = json.loads(brandInfo2[0])
        postRequest=args['postRequest']
        lang = args['postLanguage']
        brandInfo_translated=[]     
        for i in range(len(brandInfo)):
            currentConcept= brandInfo[i]['Concept']
            currentCaption = brandInfo[i]['Caption']
            TranslatedConcept= Translation.translateText(currentConcept,'EN')
            TranslatedCaption= Translation.translateText(currentCaption,'EN')
            NewElement = {'Concept' : TranslatedConcept , 'Caption' : TranslatedCaption}
            brandInfo_translated.append(NewElement)
        postRequest_translated= Translation.translateText(postRequest,'EN')
        OutputCaption2 = getCaption(postRequest_translated,brandInfo_translated)
        OutputCaption = OutputCaption2.replace('\nCaption:','')
        OutputCaption_translated = Translation.translateText(OutputCaption,lang)
        return{f'{lang} Caption' : OutputCaption_translated , 'EN Caption' : OutputCaption}
         
api.add_resource(CaptionHelper,"/caption") 


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run mybot.py locally and run Test.py by changing the BASE url, it works fine, but after uploading it to heroku I get

```
    2021-06-30T12:29:59.636123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2021-06-30T12:30:04.739160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn mybot:app`
    2021-06-30T12:30:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2021-06-30T12:30:08.776775+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-30 12:30:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    2021-06-30T12:30:08.779358+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-30 12:30:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3407 (4)
    2021-06-30T12:30:08.779588+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-30 12:30:08 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2021-06-30T12:30:08.786616+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-30 12:30:08 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
    2021-06-30T12:30:08.857596+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-06-30 12:30:08 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8    
    2021-06-30T12:30:09.055325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2021-06-30T12:30:48.368365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/caption?Initialisation=%5B%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Text1%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%2Text2%5B%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Text1%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%2Text2%7D%5D&postRequest=String&postLanguage=String" host=socialmanagerbot.herokuapp.com request_id=f2f644ae-fb4c-4967-9f53-53dec74322c5 fwd="85.190.69.200" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=400 bytes=256 protocol=https
```

Any idea what this might be due to ?

EDIT : After further investigation, the code works fine when a smaller request is sent, could it be that the request is too big ? Here I've shorten the URL but it actually looks more something like this

```
2021-06-30T18:46:20.909789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/caption?Initialisation=%5B%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+Zinc+health+benefits%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Half+of+the+world%27s+population+does+not+consume+enough+zinc%2C+yet+zinc+is+an+essential+mineral+for+the+development+of+our+immune+system.%5Cn%5CnBenefits+of+zinc%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+helps+with+hair+and+nail+growth.%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+contributes+to+normal+fertility+and+reproduction%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+supports+our+immune+defenses%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+accelerates+the+healing+of+wounds%5Cn%5CnA+need+to+boost+your+zinc+intake%3F%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Ask+our+experts+for+advice+in+store.%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Promoting+Puressentiel%27s+stress+roller%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22%5Cud83d%5Cude4f+De-stress+yourself+in+a+different+way%21+12+essential+oils+with+relaxing+and+soothing+properties+are+combined+in+Puressentiel%27s+stress+roller+to+help+you+free+yourself+from+stress.%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Very+simple+to+use%2C+apply+it+to+the+inside+of+your+two+wrists%2C+on+the+temples+and+on+the+sides+of+your+neck.%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+When+you+feel+the+stress+rising%2C+rub+your+wrists+and+breathe+deeply+the+stress+roller+scent.%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+essential+oils+usage%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Did+you+know+that+essential+oils+are+used+not+only+to+perfume+your+home+but+also+to+relieve+certain+ailments%3F%5Cn%5CnThere+are+several+ways+to+use+essential+oils%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+A+few+drops+in+your+bath+to+enjoy+their+relaxing+properties%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+In+a+diffuser+to+purify+your+environment%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+On+the+skin+to+relieve+certain+ailments.+This+practice+is+to+be+used+sparingly%2C+pure+essential+oils+must+be+mixed+with+a+base+oil+before+being+in+contact+with+the+skin.+Ask+a+professional+for+advice.%5Cn+%5CnHere+are+some+essential+oils+that+are+commonly+used%3A%5Cn+%5CnAnti-stress+%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Chamomile%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Lavender%5Cn+%5CnFor+sleep+%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Lavender%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Bergamot%5Cn+%5CnAnti-inflammatory%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Ginger%5Cn+%5CnHydration%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Patchouli%5Cn+%5CnAsk+our+experts+for+advice+in+store.%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Promoting+our+new+promo+section+on+our+website+with+-45%25+in+June%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Have+you+ever+visited+the+promos+section+on+the+website%3F+%5Cud83e%5Cudd14%5Cud83d%5Cudd25%5Cn%5CnThe+suncare+products+are+on+special.+%5Cud83c%5Cudf1e+Take+advantage+of+up+to+-45%25+off+during+the+whole+month+of+June%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+Omega-3%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Omega-3s+are+essential+fatty+acids+that+have+several+functions%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cu2705+Provide+flexibility+to+all+our+cells%5Cn%5Cu2705+Promote+the+proper+functioning+of+the+heart+and+arteries%5Cn%5Cu2705+Increase+bone+density+and+decrease+inflammation+caused+by+osteoarthritis%5Cn%5Cu2705+Slow+down+the+degeneration+of+brain+cells%5Cn%5Cu2705+Provide+energy%2C+strengthen+memory%5Cn%5Cu2705+...%5Cn%5CnFoods+rich+in+omega-3+are+nuts+and+fatty+fish+like+salmon+and+tuna+%5Cud83e%5Cudd5c%5Cud83d%5Cudc1f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+foot+care%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22At+the+beginning+of+summer%2C+our+feet+need+to+be+pampered+after+so+many+months+confined+in+our+socks+and+shoes.%5Cn%5CnHere+are+some+tips+on+how+to+take+care+of+your+feet+%3A%5Cn+%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Foot+bath%3A+add+a+few+drops+of+lavender+essential+oil+to+warm+water+and+soak+your+feet+in+it+for+about+20+minutes%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Perform+a+scrub%3A+to+remove+the+dead+cells+accumulated+on+the+surface+of+the+skin%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Remove+calluses%3A+rub+2+tablespoons+of+sugar+and+a+little+olive+oil+into+the+palm+of+your+hands%2C+then+massage+your+feet+with%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Moisturize%3A+Use+a+moisturizing+body+or+hand+cream+to+make+them+soft+and+supple%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+natural+solutions+to+mosquitoes%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Summer+is+coming%21+With+the+sun+%5Cud83c%5Cudf1e%2C+the+vacations%2C+but+also+the+mosquitoes+%5Cud83e%5Cudd9f%21+%5Cn+%5CnZoom+on+natural+solutions+to+keep+these+little+undesirables+away+and+spend+the+summer+in+peace.+%5Cud83d%5Cudc4c%5Cn+%5Cn-+Lemongrass%2C+basil%2C+lavender%3A+to+place+near+your+windows+or+bedroom%2C+mosquitoes+will+flee+their+smell.%5Cud83c%5Cudf3f+%5Cn-+Geranium%3A+very+beautiful+flower+and+natural+mosquito+repellent.+%5Cud83c%5Cudf38%5Cn-+Lime+and+cloves%3A+cut+a+lime+in+half%2C+prick+each+half+with+cloves%2C+mosquitoes+hate+the+smell+of+this+duo.+%5Cud83c%5Cudf4b%5Cn-+Lemon+eucalyptus+essential+oil%3A+very+effective+mosquito+repellent+and+relieves+itching.+%5Cud83d%5Cudca6+%5Cn-+Vinegar%3A+excellent+grandma%27s+solution+to+chase+away+these+undesirables.+Put+a+few+drops+on+your+clothes+or+sheets.+%5Cud83d%5Cudc93+%5Cn+%5CnStop+by+the+parapharmacy+for+professional+advice+%5Cud83d%5Cude0e%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+high+grass+season%2C+allergies+and+hay+fever%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22It%27s+high+grass+season%2C+and+therefore+hay+fever+season.%5CnWe+are+reaching+the+peak+now%2C+people+allergic+to+grass+pollen+can+feel+it...%5Cn%5CnHere+are+some+simple+things+to+do+on+a+daily+basis%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Avoid+drying+your+linens+outside%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Remember+to+dry+your+hair+well+before+going+outside%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Air+your+room+earlier+in+the+morning%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Prefer+a+diet+rich+in+vitamin+E+and+Omega+3%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Consume+honey+regularly%5CnDiffuse+purifying+essential+oils+such+as+eucalyptus+or+Ravintsara+in+each+room+of+the+house%5Cn%5CnAt+the+slightest+discomfort%2C+act+immediately.+Consult+your+doctor.%5Cn%5CnThe+Medi-Market+team+is+also+at+your+disposal+for+useful+advice+to+limit+allergies.%5Cn%5CnTake+good+care+of+yourself.+%5Cud83d%5Cude4f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+hair+loss+prevention%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Should+you+be+concerned+about+losing+your+hair%3F+%5Cud83e%5Cudd28%5Cn%5CnOur+head+has+over+120%2C000+hairs%2C+and+it+is+healthy+and+normal+to+lose+about+30-50+hairs+a+day.+This+is+part+of+the+renewal+process.+Take+our+test+and+see+if+you+need+to+worry%3A%5Cn%5Cn1%5Cufe0f+Wash+your+hair%5Cn2%5Cufe0f+Lay+out+a+blank+sheet+of+paper+on+a+flat+surface%5Cn3%5Cufe0f+Tilt+your+head+over+the+sheet%5Cn4%5Cufe0f+Run+your+fingers+through+your+hair+from+the+roots+to+the+ends+%285+times%29%5Cn5%5Cufe0f+Count+the+number+of+hairs+present+on+the+sheet%5Cn%5CnIf+there+are+less+than+50%2C+you+have+nothing+to+worry+about%21+Is+it+more%3F+You+still+have+nothing+to+worry+about%2C+you+are+perfect+just+the+way+you+are+%5Cud83d%5Cudc9d%5Cud83d%5Cudc9d%5Cud83d%5Cudc9d%5Cn%5CnStop+by+the+parapharmacy+for+professional+advice+%5Cud83d%5Cude0e%22%7D%5D&postRequest=Information+sur+la+vitamine+C&postLanguage=FR" host=socialmanagerbot.herokuapp.com request_id=9a358ce5-936e-4acb-b8b8-bc5d739d7976 fwd="85.190.69.200" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=256 protocol=https
```

EDIT 2 : Changed from GET request to POST request to test if this was due to char limit but still same issue. I'm kinda running out of idea here - Anyone had experience with this before ?

```
2021-06-30T19:06:38.372020+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/caption?Initialisation=%5B%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+Zinc+health+benefits%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Half+of+the+world%27s+population+does+not+consume+enough+zinc%2C+yet+zinc+is+an+essential+mineral+for+the+development+of+our+immune+system.%5Cn%5CnBenefits+of+zinc%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+helps+with+hair+and+nail+growth.%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+contributes+to+normal+fertility+and+reproduction%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+supports+our+immune+defenses%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+It+accelerates+the+healing+of+wounds%5Cn%5CnA+need+to+boost+your+zinc+intake%3F%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Ask+our+experts+for+advice+in+store.%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Promoting+Puressentiel%27s+stress+roller%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22%5Cud83d%5Cude4f+De-stress+yourself+in+a+different+way%21+12+essential+oils+with+relaxing+and+soothing+properties+are+combined+in+Puressentiel%27s+stress+roller+to+help+you+free+yourself+from+stress.%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Very+simple+to+use%2C+apply+it+to+the+inside+of+your+two+wrists%2C+on+the+temples+and+on+the+sides+of+your+neck.%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+When+you+feel+the+stress+rising%2C+rub+your+wrists+and+breathe+deeply+the+stress+roller+scent.%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+essential+oils+usage%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Did+you+know+that+essential+oils+are+used+not+only+to+perfume+your+home+but+also+to+relieve+certain+ailments%3F%5Cn%5CnThere+are+several+ways+to+use+essential+oils%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+A+few+drops+in+your+bath+to+enjoy+their+relaxing+properties%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+In+a+diffuser+to+purify+your+environment%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+On+the+skin+to+relieve+certain+ailments.+This+practice+is+to+be+used+sparingly%2C+pure+essential+oils+must+be+mixed+with+a+base+oil+before+being+in+contact+with+the+skin.+Ask+a+professional+for+advice.%5Cn+%5CnHere+are+some+essential+oils+that+are+commonly+used%3A%5Cn+%5CnAnti-stress+%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Chamomile%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Lavender%5Cn+%5CnFor+sleep+%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Lavender%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Bergamot%5Cn+%5CnAnti-inflammatory%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Ginger%5Cn+%5CnHydration%3A%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Patchouli%5Cn+%5CnAsk+our+experts+for+advice+in+store.%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Promoting+our+new+promo+section+on+our+website+with+-45%25+in+June%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Have+you+ever+visited+the+promos+section+on+the+website%3F+%5Cud83e%5Cudd14%5Cud83d%5Cudd25%5Cn%5CnThe+suncare+products+are+on+special.+%5Cud83c%5Cudf1e+Take+advantage+of+up+to+-45%25+off+during+the+whole+month+of+June%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+Omega-3%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Omega-3s+are+essential+fatty+acids+that+have+several+functions%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cu2705+Provide+flexibility+to+all+our+cells%5Cn%5Cu2705+Promote+the+proper+functioning+of+the+heart+and+arteries%5Cn%5Cu2705+Increase+bone+density+and+decrease+inflammation+caused+by+osteoarthritis%5Cn%5Cu2705+Slow+down+the+degeneration+of+brain+cells%5Cn%5Cu2705+Provide+energy%2C+strengthen+memory%5Cn%5Cu2705+...%5Cn%5CnFoods+rich+in+omega-3+are+nuts+and+fatty+fish+like+salmon+and+tuna+%5Cud83e%5Cudd5c%5Cud83d%5Cudc1f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+foot+care%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22At+the+beginning+of+summer%2C+our+feet+need+to+be+pampered+after+so+many+months+confined+in+our+socks+and+shoes.%5Cn%5CnHere+are+some+tips+on+how+to+take+care+of+your+feet+%3A%5Cn+%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Foot+bath%3A+add+a+few+drops+of+lavender+essential+oil+to+warm+water+and+soak+your+feet+in+it+for+about+20+minutes%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Perform+a+scrub%3A+to+remove+the+dead+cells+accumulated+on+the+surface+of+the+skin%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Remove+calluses%3A+rub+2+tablespoons+of+sugar+and+a+little+olive+oil+into+the+palm+of+your+hands%2C+then+massage+your+feet+with%5Cn%5Cu2714%5Cufe0f+Moisturize%3A+Use+a+moisturizing+body+or+hand+cream+to+make+them+soft+and+supple%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+natural+solutions+to+mosquitoes%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Summer+is+coming%21+With+the+sun+%5Cud83c%5Cudf1e%2C+the+vacations%2C+but+also+the+mosquitoes+%5Cud83e%5Cudd9f%21+%5Cn+%5CnZoom+on+natural+solutions+to+keep+these+little+undesirables+away+and+spend+the+summer+in+peace.+%5Cud83d%5Cudc4c%5Cn+%5Cn-+Lemongrass%2C+basil%2C+lavender%3A+to+place+near+your+windows+or+bedroom%2C+mosquitoes+will+flee+their+smell.%5Cud83c%5Cudf3f+%5Cn-+Geranium%3A+very+beautiful+flower+and+natural+mosquito+repellent.+%5Cud83c%5Cudf38%5Cn-+Lime+and+cloves%3A+cut+a+lime+in+half%2C+prick+each+half+with+cloves%2C+mosquitoes+hate+the+smell+of+this+duo.+%5Cud83c%5Cudf4b%5Cn-+Lemon+eucalyptus+essential+oil%3A+very+effective+mosquito+repellent+and+relieves+itching.+%5Cud83d%5Cudca6+%5Cn-+Vinegar%3A+excellent+grandma%27s+solution+to+chase+away+these+undesirables.+Put+a+few+drops+on+your+clothes+or+sheets.+%5Cud83d%5Cudc93+%5Cn+%5CnStop+by+the+parapharmacy+for+professional+advice+%5Cud83d%5Cude0e%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+high+grass+season%2C+allergies+and+hay+fever%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22It%27s+high+grass+season%2C+and+therefore+hay+fever+season.%5CnWe+are+reaching+the+peak+now%2C+people+allergic+to+grass+pollen+can+feel+it...%5Cn%5CnHere+are+some+simple+things+to+do+on+a+daily+basis%3A%5Cn%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Avoid+drying+your+linens+outside%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Remember+to+dry+your+hair+well+before+going+outside%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Air+your+room+earlier+in+the+morning%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Prefer+a+diet+rich+in+vitamin+E+and+Omega+3%5Cn%5Cud83d%5Cudc49+Consume+honey+regularly%5CnDiffuse+purifying+essential+oils+such+as+eucalyptus+or+Ravintsara+in+each+room+of+the+house%5Cn%5CnAt+the+slightest+discomfort%2C+act+immediately.+Consult+your+doctor.%5Cn%5CnThe+Medi-Market+team+is+also+at+your+disposal+for+useful+advice+to+limit+allergies.%5Cn%5CnTake+good+care+of+yourself.+%5Cud83d%5Cude4f%22%7D%2C+%7B%22Concept%22%3A+%22Information+about+hair+loss+prevention%22%2C+%22Caption%22%3A+%22Should+you+be+concerned+about+losing+your+hair%3F+%5Cud83e%5Cudd28%5Cn%5CnOur+head+has+over+120%2C000+hairs%2C+and+it+is+healthy+and+normal+to+lose+about+30-50+hairs+a+day.+This+is+part+of+the+renewal+process.+Take+our+test+and+see+if+you+need+to+worry%3A%5Cn%5Cn1%5Cufe0f+Wash+your+hair%5Cn2%5Cufe0f+Lay+out+a+blank+sheet+of+paper+on+a+flat+surface%5Cn3%5Cufe0f+Tilt+your+head+over+the+sheet%5Cn4%5Cufe0f+Run+your+fingers+through+your+hair+from+the+roots+to+the+ends+%285+times%29%5Cn5%5Cufe0f+Count+the+number+of+hairs+present+on+the+sheet%5Cn%5CnIf+there+are+less+than+50%2C+you+have+nothing+to+worry+about%21+Is+it+more%3F+You+still+have+nothing+to+worry+about%2C+you+are+perfect+just+the+way+you+are+%5Cud83d%5Cudc9d%5Cud83d%5Cudc9d%5Cud83d%5Cudc9d%5Cn%5CnStop+by+the+parapharmacy+for+professional+advice+%5Cud83d%5Cude0e%22%7D%5D&postRequest=Information+sur+la+vitamine+C&postLanguage=FR" host=socialmanagerbot.herokuapp.com request_id=49a8b074-ef7b-4271-b50f-8f72d5b71bbd fwd="85.190.69.200" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=400 bytes=256 protocol=https
```

Comment: Could you post few more lines of Heroku logs.

Comment: Just added the lines before, does it provide you wiith more info?

Comment: Anybody can help me ?